# Different css styles of .modal-open for different modals

Tags: html, css

i have a modal with id #exampleModal , and there are three more modals in website.

What i want is when i open the #exampleModal the .modal-open class should have this css

```
    .modal-open{
       overflow-y : "scroll" 
    }
```

And when the other three opens they should have the default that bootstrap gives?

Comment: This is precisely what CSS does with an ID selector. Do you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Good practice if you have multiple Modals (or multiple carousels/accordions etc) is to make sure they all have a different `id`. This is important for W3C validation especially.

Best Bootstrap Tip - The `id` can be anything you want. Then you can style that `id` any way you want.

Let's say you label each one as `id="modal-1"` and `id="modal-2"` etc.

Then, in your CSS all the `id`'s can be edited independently of each other...

```
#modal-1{
  /* Your styling */
}

#modal-2{
  /* Your styling */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap runs this automatically when modal is shown:

```
var exampleModal = document.getElementById('exampleModal')

exampleModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function (event) {
     exampleModal.style.overflowY = "scroll";
})
```

Comment: This seems like vast overkill when one line of CSS does the same.

Comment: I agree, when in Bootstrap 5 they went to all the effort of removing JS... Why would we add any?